# ERROR uploading: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2019' with JSON data upload

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am using python to upload some JSON data to the application UI but getting following error.

**ERROR uploading: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 5735: Body ('â') is not valid Latin-1. Use body.encode('utf-8') if you want to send it encoded in UTF-8.**

The program takes the input from a sample.json file which includes a special character ( ' ) and that's giving the error.

**Value: amex%?'**

My code looks like:

```
def read_from_file(file_path, target_path=None):

    try:
        f = open(file_path, "r")
        data = json.load(f)
        f.close()

        if target_path:
            result_obj = []
            for obj in data:
                if target_path in obj['Key']:
                    result_obj.append(obj)
            data = result_obj

    except Exception as e:
        print ("ERROR reading file:", e, file=sys.stderr)
        exit(1)

    return data


def upload(server, token, data):

    params = {"token": token}

    for obj in data:
        try:
            payload = obj['Value']
            url = server + obj['Key']

            response = requests.put(url, data=payload, params=params)
            if response.status_code != 200:
                raise Exception("HTTP code %s on PUT %s" % (response.status_code, url))

        except Exception as e:
            print ("ERROR uploading:", e, file=sys.stderr)
            exit(1)
```

Can somebody please advise where I need to change my code to include special character ( ' ) while upload?

Comment: did you write that special character in word or on some windows platform, thats a windows right quotation mark. Just use a regular `'`

Comment: Hi @Craicerjack, the program downloads some key-values from a web UI and uploads to some different URLs. So one KV includes this line "We’re just"
So, the program is able to download the value but while uploading, it's giving error due to the special character in the line "We're"
I am running the code on Linux OS.

Comment: I think I am able to fix the issue with following update.

```
payload = obj['Value'].encode('utf-8')
```

but now getting different error for blank values.

```
ERROR uploading: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

```

How can I ignore this?

Comment: That means that this - `obj['Value']` is `None`

Comment: can you include sample json data?

Comment: @Craicerjack Here is the data from sample.json:::

`
    {
        "CreateIndex": 49700,
        "Flags": 0,
        "Key": "Nitesh/convert",
        "LockIndex": 0,
        "ModifyIndex": 49700,
        "Value": "null"
`